# How to search list view with Edit Text in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to search `ListView` by writing something inside the `EditText`. like if I write first to words "Su" so the content in `ListView` with first two words as "Su" should come on top.

This is my code:

```
Sear = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.Search);
    Sear.setThreshold(1);

    Sear.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

            sdAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
        }

        @Override

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Right now when I write something in my `EditText` the `ListView` dissapears. 
I am having 5 columns in my `ListView`. i want to search the name of that specific person and search the `ListView` with that name.

This is the Adapter:

```
sdAdapter = new StationDetails_Adapter(AllStations.this, R.layout.listview_row2 , Stationlist);
```

Comment: Try here if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038861/filter-on-listview-disappear-listitems-while-entering-something-into-edittext

Comment: You wouldn't be searching the listview. You would search "Stationlist".

Comment: Have you called `notifyDatasetChanged()` while filter your data?

Comment: i am confused. nothing working

Comment: I did help. I gave sort of a copy-paste job below.

Comment: Okay. Show your `StationDetails_Adapter` class.

Comment: guys can u help on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861923/search-list-view-list-view-dissapears-when-type-in-edit-text

Answer (score 1):

Searching in a `ListView` can be done with local SQLite DB. I suppose you shuld have knowledge about SQLite Database then follow the steps like:

1) Set `ListView` adapter and store all data in SQLite Database

2) write a simple query on DB end like: `select * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME where column_name like '%+your_search_keyword+%'`

3)execute this query while you are in `onTextChanged()` method.

4) use cursor to get all data against search keyword from SQLite DB and set the `ListView` adapter

5) If cursor do not return any data means you have no record against search keyword.

**Other Way:** Other than SQLite DB you can set adapter and filter on a specific search keyword like:

**For Example:**

```
    String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                    "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                    "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

            // Adding items to listview
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

The above example is referred from [Android Hive Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Comment: help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861923/search-list-view-list-view-dissapears-when-type-in-edit-text

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement filterable in your listAdapter.
Below example does the same thing that you want.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: Why are you posting the link as a answer. It's a better to post some part of code. So it may be solve the OP problem.

Comment: @piyush... Dude if its already working code at some other place, then its be better to share link rather than pasting a code. Otherwise, developers may get confused.

Comment: Then you need to post as a comment!

Comment: help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861923/search-list-view-list-view-dissapears-when-type-in-edit-text